# Connect Facebook PHP or JS SDK to Joomla

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, joomla, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

How can I install Facebook SDKs in Joomla 3.0? Can I do this via FTP or some component/module/code change? Because my website is hosted by a hosting company, and so I don't have access to server options or console.

I know there are modules for Joomla that allow use of Facebook SDK, but as far as I know they allow only basic functions like logging in via Facebook etc., and I need to add some PHP SDK, Javascript SDK or cURL code that I got from Graph API Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

To add the Facebook javascript SDK to your site you need to go to Extensions => Templates => your template and edit the index.php. You should add the code snippet right below the start of the `<body>`tag. Then you need to add a custom module, I recommend using the the Custom HTML advanced module because it doesn't filter your input, to be able to place your facebook code where ever you want.